# When dumping assetic, using MopaBootstrapBundle, Runtime Exception occurs: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, less

Below is the complete output:

```
> php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\app\console assetic:dump
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.

[file+] C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\app/../web/css/992f634.css
'stty' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.



  [RuntimeException]                                                  
  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  




assetic:dump [--watch] [--force] [--period="..."] [write_to]



Process finished with exit code 1 at 23:12:02.
Execution time: 1,118 ms.
```

Am installing MopaBootstrapBundle. I am able to access the site without styling. What could have gone wrong? below is my config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    # java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: C:\nodejs
            node_paths: [C:\nodejs\node_modules]
        cssembed:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.4.5.jar
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
```

Please help me, I don't know what else to do. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to get [less](http://lesscss.org/) to work with my Symfony2 installation, so instead I used [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/). here is how to configure lessphp with [MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle) and effectively eliminate my problem. BTW this solution is also like how to run [MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle) using a Windows Machine.

```
//add this to your deps file, then install
[lessphp]
    git = "https://github.com/leafo/lessphp.git"
    target = "/lessphp"

//add this to your autoload.php
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    //some codes here
    'lessc'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/lessphp',
));
```

---

```
//add this to config.yml
assetic:
    filters:
        less: ~
        lessphp:
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
```

---

```
//override the layout.html.twig, either only to your bundle or from the app/Resources
{% extends 'MopaBootstrapBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block head_style %}
    {% stylesheets
        '@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock head_style %}
```

Hope this helps. =)

Comment: Thanks!  My prod environment didn't have node so this makes a great alternative.  It's a little simpler on 2.1 as well, you just need to add it to composer.json and change the config line path from vendor/lessphp to vendor/leafo/lessphp